# Wrong 'convertView' object while scrolling a list view

Tags: android, position, convertview, getview

My problem is that when I'm scrolling a list view I'm getting wrong convertView, but the position is right.

I have 3 items in my Listview, on load 'position' parameter is called with index **'0'** and convertView is **null**.

When I scroll one by one, to the next item 'position' is **'1'** and convertView is **null** also.

The problem is on item 3, the 'position' is **'2'** BUT the 'convertView' is **not null**, it is populated by the **first item convertView**.

Why is that  ?

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);

            postViewHolder                              = new PostViewHolder();
            postViewHolder.commentsImageButton          = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postAddCommentsImageButton);

            itemView.setTag(postViewHolder);
        }else{
            postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }
```

}

Comment: why do you need position in the convertView?

Comment: return statement is missing. `return itemView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        PostViewHolder postViewHolder = null;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
            postViewHolder                              = new PostViewHolder();
            postViewHolder.commentsImageButton          = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postAddCommentsImageButton);

            itemView.setTag(postViewHolder);
        }else{
            postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }
        postViewHolder.position    = position;
        :do your stuff with postViewHolder
        :
        return itemView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will only get N null items in your listView, this value N will change depending on how many rows enter in your screen.

For example if in your screen there are 3 rows, you will probably have 4 or 5 row items. This is because Android recycle the old views into new ones.

If you need to keep track of the holder position move your `postViewHolder.position` out of your if / else statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've removed the postViewHolder.position from the question, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I understand that it recycle old views, but with viewHolder Pattern it will load a recycled convertView, which is wrong, all the views from 'findViewByID' will direct the recycled convertView and will not create a new one.

Comment: And why do you need to create a new one? That is how ListViews work. If you have more items in your listviews, the will be recycled into these N views which are the views you need to display the information.